# Cartthrob order editing -- save order in draft status?

Tags: cartthrob

I need to be able to easily add, change, and delete items from finished orders. The most ideal solution to this would be to have all orders saved in some kind of 'draft' status and only finalize them after they're processed by staff, as has been [mentioned on CT's forums](http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/4927/#25049).

I'm currently attempting to hack something together using javascript to allow staff to add and configure products (and then use Cartthrob's inventory reduce tag) but wondering if anyone else facing this problem has come up with a way to keep orders in the cart until after staff has finished with them? Or to put it a different way, is there any way to give a staff member access to the cart prior to it being submitted?

We don't use any kind of payment gateway so there's no reason the order needs to be finalized before staff gets to it.

Answer (score 2):

What version of CT are you using? I can see in the admin that under settings/orders you can set the status under 'payment being processed'.

Maybe there some way you can use that to hack a solution?
I haven't done it myself but it looks like there may be a way.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I have the most recent version. 

I don't think anything involving order status will work, because as soon as it is submitted, it stops being in the cart, and becomes an order. I want to be able to work with the line items as if they were still in the cart, which I'm instead doing with Safecracker forms.

The only way this would work would be if I had online orders not really submit, just save and notify staff of the order -- but AFAIK there is no easy way for staff to access cart contents of un-finished orders. 

I just have a rather unfortunate situation where orders change *all the time*.